Can you use the word "bill" to as your friend to check what movies are being screened at the cinema? (What other words can you use?)
While looking for a definition for the word "bill" in another context I stumbled on this definition:
"bill" (noun):
"9. entertainment scheduled for presentation; program: a good bill at the movies." (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010)
Would someone use this word let's say, if you invited your friend to go to the movies with you and you wanted to ask him to check the time of the movie that you planned to see or what movies are playing that day in general? I.e. would you say "Check the bill at the cinema" to your friend? I think I've heard the word "showtimes" used for this but never this word. (I'm asking about the worldwide usage not just the U.K)

“Bill” or “playbill” used to have this secondary meaning, but I have not seen it used in print for 50 years easily, except in the (rare and metaphorical) fixed phrase “what’s on the bill?”, meaning what do we have planned?
The usage lives on in the name of the “magazine” Playbill.

Yes it's definitely old fashioned, more likely in the days when you'd go to the cinema and see a b-movie, short films, and news before the main feature. It's still used eg at a concert with support bands, or another event with multiple performers.

I haven't heard the word "bill" used for movie schedule.
"Show timings" or Show time are more common in our country.
We even have a movie magazine named, "Showtime"

The short answer is "yes".
As you see from the definition, the bill is a timetable of films showing at a cinema either posted outside on a noticeboard or published in the local newspaper, website or social media. I think it's more likely to be used in AmE rather than BrE where the word programme is more common. I don't know the usage in other English speaking countries.
It can also apply to theatres and other places of public entertainment where scheduled performances or events are on offer.
